# Какая логика работы Comparator()

Tags: java

Определен массив чисел

```
ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(10);
list.add(-70);
list.add(99);
```

Отсортировать значения листа можно по возрастанию с использованием метода из класса Collections;
Collections.sort(list);   - метод передает массив, пробегается по элементам сортирует их и возвращает новый отсортированный list, - это понятно.

Какая логика работы при сортировки по убыванию?

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                int a = ((Integer)o1).intValue();  //элемент преобразуется в Integer
                int b = ((Integer)o2).intValue();   //элемент преобразуется в Integer
                return a < b ? 1 : a == b ? 0 : -1;  //выполняется сравнение и возврат наименьшего элемента
            }
        });
```

Непонятно как работает анонимный класс?
Каким образом берутся элементы из list  и передаются в качестве параметров методу compare()?

Comment: Вы ведь уже посмотрели как изнутри работает Collections.sort/Arrays.sort? Полагаю, что нет, иначе подобных вопросов бы не задавали. Но ничего страшного. [Наслаждайтесь](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#174).

Answer (score 1):

> Непонятно как работает анонимный класс?

Он работает так как вы его закодили. в приведенном примере он делает следующее:

```
return a < b ? 1 : a == b ? 0 : -1; // if (a<b) return 1; if (a==b) return 0 else return -1;
```

> Каким образом берутся элементы из list и передаются в качестве параметров методу compare()?

Метод sort класса Collections реализует один из алгоритмов сортировки, который для сравнивания элементов использует ваш "кастомный" компаратор.